# check drop table statement drops the hive table or not

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, scripting, hiveql

I was using below code for deleting the hive table. In the shell script, I need to know where it was able to delete the table or not, also it make be the possibility that we might try to delete the table which is currently not present so I am hoping that should through error.

```
if $(beeline -u $beeline_jdbc_url_qa -n $beeline_username_qa -p $beeline_password_file_qa --silent=true -e 'drop table '''$hive_database_name_qa'''.'''${hTbl}''' ')
then
        echo "TBL $hTbl successfully dropped"
        # my other logic
else
        echo "failed to dropped TBL $hTbl"
        exit 1
fi
```

But in all the case hive table exist or not it always comes into "successfully drop statement".

Do anyone know how to solve this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below syntax. Replace table name with your table

```
beeline -u ${HIVE_URL} ${HIVE_USER} ${HIVE_CONF} --hivevar env=${HIVE_ENV} -e "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST PURGE"
RC=$?
if [ $RC -ne 0 ]
then
     echo "[Error]: Beeline command failed with Return_Code: $RC !"
     exit 1
fi
echo "TEST table Dropped Successfully"
```

Comment: I do understand that if the beeline failure happens due to the wrong credential passed this would go into error part but what about if the table is not present in hive database and beeline is trying to drop it, it should throw into error part only?? please correct me

Comment: updated code. Updated script will only drop the table if it exists. It will not give error in case table not exists. It will only give error if something goes wrong fron hive side.